# Setting OneDrive location in Windows 10 Guest to host shared folder in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, windows-10, virtualbox, fedora, onedrive

My only solution so far to really have OneDrive running on my Fedora workstation is to have Windows 10 in a VirtualBox VM. I've set up a shared machine folder between the two, and I can access the shared folder on the Windows guest, mounting the drive as a Network drive on `G:\` with the network drive location being `\\VboxSrv`.

However, when I try to set the OneDrive folder location to the mounted drive G:\ or a folder within it, I'm met with an error that the folder cannot be used.

How can I make the files accessible on the Host (Fedora 30)?